# How can I make responsive app that work in every device?

Tags: flutter, dynamic, size, responsive

I have used ScreenUtilInit() in my flutter application. In that designSize: Size(360, 690) or designSize:ScreenUtil.defaultSize, what should I put. And what is advantages in both?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of your actual displayable widget with the `MediaQuery` class.

```
double card_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 15 / 16;
double card_height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4;
```

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches to creating Flutter apps with responsive design:

- Use the LayoutBuilder class
  From its builder property, you get a BoxConstraints object
- Use the MediaQuery.of() method in your build functions
  This gives you the size, orientation, etc, of your current app

Answer (score 0):

You may create a size_config.dart file with the following

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {   
static MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;   
static double? screenWidth;   
static double? screenHeight;  
static double? defaultSize;   
static Orientation? orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData!.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData!.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData!.orientation;   } }

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size 
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {   
    double? screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;   
// 812 is the layout height that designer use   
return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight!; }

// Get the proportionate width as per screen size 
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {   
double? screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;   
// 375 is the layout width that designer use   
return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth!; }
```

Simply call the function getProportionateScreenHeight/Width and put in the values in pixels according to your design. You may change the default canvas size of height:812 or width: 375 according to your wireframe.

For example

```
  return SizedBox(
      height: getProportionateScreenHeight(
        60.0,
      ),
  // 60 is pixels in specified in your wireframe design but it gets translated 
  // into approximately 7% of the screen height ratio on your mobile device screen
```

Remember to call `SizeConfig().init(context);` like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
```

in your starting screen else you will receive an error

Hope this helps in what you are working on!